# pyenv using right python version but using wrong libraries folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyenv

Hello I currently run on 3.8 python. I need to execute a 3.6 version script that uses the Crypto and time libraries. 
So I installed pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv. 
I installed the version of python I wanted : `pyenv install 3.6.8`.
Then I went to my project folder `cd Documents/CSC/myProject/`.
I executed : `pyenv local 3.6.8`. I verified the pip version : `pip 18.1 from /home/alex/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
.` That was okay. Then I installed Crypto on the 3.6 version.
But when I run the script I have the following error: `File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 77, in collect
    t = time.clock()
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'`
Why does python search the 3.8 version of Crypto even if I have the 3.6 version on local.
When I am in the folder the 3.6 version ?
I'm a bit confused.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whats causing the problem but i would suggest you to pipenv instead. It is more reliable and simpler in my personal opinion
You can install it using   `pip install pipenv` and then do `pipenv shell` to use it. 
Read more about it [here](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I will do that for my future projects. But for this project that is really light I'd like to understand better why I have this problem :)